# How to use CMake macro as INSTALL_COMMAND in ExternalProject_Add?

Tags: cmake, dependencies, installation

I have a header only library, that I include in my project using [`ExternalProject_Add`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/ExternalProject.html). The install command should just copy a folder. Since this should work on Windows and Linux, I tried to use [`file(COPY ...)`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3Afile).

```
INSTALL_COMMAND "file(COPY ../src/include DESTINATION ../install/include)"
```

This gives an error since `INSTALL_COMMAND` gets executed as shell command. How can I use a CMake macro instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CMake has a "command mode", i.e. [`cmake -E ...`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake.1.html) which provides some cross-platform filesystem commands.  To see all `-E` options, just run `cmake -E`.

To invoke CMake itself from within a CMakeLists.txt file, you can use the variable [`CMAKE_COMMAND`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_COMMAND.html):

```
INSTALL_COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory ../src/include ../install/include
```